# I am struggling with my header in CSS not resizing correctly.

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am struggling making my mobile first design work as my header doesn't resize in mobile view. I am fairly happy with how it looks in full-screen. I couldn't make any media query work. the files can be downloaded and view on my git-hub account at: https://github.com/ErikRobles/Psycology
If anyone can take a look and help me out, I would appreciate it. Thank you in advance. 
[The image shows what I want in small to mobile browsers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp02D.png)

Comment: Show us in fiddle instead of downloading from Git

Comment: [I did some work for you](https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/QOGoZK), is it something like this?

Comment: Hello Dhaval. I tried it in jsfiddle and codepen and it doesn't look anything like what I am working on. I uploaded it to my drive account with an open link if you would like to download it on to your pc. Cheers. Link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GNd3JGwfAPmmCz5NP9Yr6W9HL861GUSp?usp=sharing and https://drive.google.com/open?id=1I8zzXyKyMUd8LHNOfmZW2y5qkwq3CZK9

Comment: Ok, so you want to make it responsive right?

Comment: Yes. I tried to use media queries but they just won't do anything

Comment: Ok will look tonight and let you know soon.

Comment: Thanks mate. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hello Dhaval. I have added the photos in the codepen you provided me the other day. Thank you for your work on this. As you can see, the site is just about where I want it on just about all screens. However, as you will see in this link: https://codepen.io/ErikJamesRobles/pen/QOdxYo the slider image does not resize because I think something is preventing my media queries or I am just not doing them right. Thanks again for your help. Cheers.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: Update. Just about there. I used the following code:  @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {     // IE10+ CSS here } And targeted my header items. I'll post the new code in GitHub tomorrow.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you might need `max-width:100%`
Which will not let your carousel overflow

You might want to remove the unwanted space as well, which is created while resizing.

Please check **[this pen](https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/QOdBOw)**, thank you for putting it in Codepen it helps us a lot.

Comment: Great. This is super. I also added a min width of 740px which kept the slider image from shrinking beyond legibility. I really appreciate you looking at this. I can't thank you enough. I'll make sure to post you and let you know when the site goes live. Cheers Mate.

Answer (score 0):

You're taking elements out of the normal flow of content by setting them to `position: absolute`. This means that they won't affect the positioning of other elements.

[See the MDN article on the `position` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning).